# JSON null value in result of grails.converters.JSON.parse()

Tags: grails

Running following code in Groovy console from Grails 2.5.1 (or just as part of Grails application):

```
import grails.converters.JSON
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONObject

def jsonObj = JSON.parse('{ "a": null }')
def results = [
    (null != jsonObj.a),
    (JSONObject.NULL == jsonObj.a),
    (null == jsonObj.b),
    (JSONObject.NULL != jsonObj.b),
]
```

gives this result `[false, false, true, true]`

Looks to me as bug, the first two expressions should be `true` or am I missing something?

Comment: under Grails 2.4.4 I get [true, true, true, true] , tried it on any other versions ?

Comment: Mentioned code worked OK in application that began with Grails 2.1 and were upgraded regularly to Grails 2.2.X, 2.3.X, 2.5.0. Described problem was observed after recent upgrade to 2.5.1. I'm just asking to be sure that I haven't missed something, before I will raise issue at Grails GitHub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is desired change of behavior introduced in Grails 2.5.1.

Related issues on Grails GitHub:

[#9162 issue raised by me](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9162)

[#9129 that caused the change](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9129)

[#9143 removal of JSONObject.Null - planned for Grails 3.1](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9143)

Comment: So many days of searching.  After upgrading to Grails 3 with no mention in the docs of where JSONObject.NULL went, I went so far as to migrate everything to use JSONNull (unsuccessfully).  Then I found this.. You just summed up a whole lotta history for me with those 3 links.  Thanks friend.